# Is project.afterEvaluate the right way to access plugin configuration to create tasks

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

## Background

I'm currently writing a plugin that uses some configuration and then creates a variable number of tasks based on that configuration. The below is a simplified version of it

##### Example configuration:

```
public class TypedMaterialsExtension{

    private Property<Boolean> createTheTask;

    public TypedMaterialsExtension(Project project) {
        createTheTask = project.getObjects().property(Boolean.class);
        createTheTask.set(false);
    }

    public Property<Boolean> getCreateTheTask() {
        return createTheTask;
    }

}
```

Use in build.gradle:

```
typedMaterials{
  createTheTask = true
}
```

##### Example plugin

```
public class TypedMaterialsPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public void apply(Project project) {

        TypedMaterialsExtension extension = project.getExtensions().create("typedMaterials", TypedMaterialsExtension.class, project);

        if(extension.getCreateTheTask().get()){
                project.getTasks().register("beforeTask", TypedJarMaterials.class, task -> {});
            project.getTasks().named("compileJava").configure(compileJava -> {
                compileJava.dependsOn("beforeTask");
            });
        }

        project.afterEvaluate(p -> {
            if(extension.getCreateTheTask().get()){
                project.getTasks().register("afterTask", TypedJarMaterials.class, task -> {});
                project.getTasks().named("compileJava").configure(compileJava -> {
                    compileJava.dependsOn("afterTask");
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`afterTask` gets registered `beforeTask` does not

## Question

I'm finding that the config is only available when accessed within an project.afterEvaluate lambda. In the example `afterTask` gets registered but `beforeTask` does not. I can obviously put everything within a `project.afterEvaluate` block but I understand that is bad practice. What should I be doing to creating tasks conditionally based on some config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a property, use a function.

```java
public class TypedMaterialsExtension {

    private final Project project;

    public TypedMaterialsExtension(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    public void createTheTask() {
        project.getTasks().register("timelyTask", Task.class, task -> {});
        project.getTasks().named("compileJava").configure(compileJava -> {
            compileJava.dependsOn("timelyTask");
        });
    }

}
```

And in `build.gradle`:

```
typedMaterials {
    createTheTask()
}
```

Then the code to add the task runs as the build script is executed.

Properties are more useful for modifying the configuration of something, as opposed to (as in this question) a binary question of whether an object exists or not; and once the object exists, you can use Gradle's lazy API to pick up the property values.

Comment: Ooo, very cool. That works wonderfully (in both this toy example and in the real plugin I'm creating)